# Delegate callable to specific GridGain node

Tags: java, gridgain

I have a question regarding GridGain. How can I delegate a callable to a specific GridGain node? From what I can see in GridGain's API, you do not have control over selecting a specific node. Can anyone help me with this?

something like:

```
clientNode.node(uuid).call(callable);
```

the problem is that if you get a node from the

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have an unfinished thought after your code.

Comment: Could you provide some more code? What is clientNode an instance of? I looked at some [documentation](http://gridgain.com/sdk/6.5.0/javadoc/org/gridgain/grid/compute/GridCompute.html) that suggests you provide callable instances to a GridCompute object (not a node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how this can be done in GridGain:

```
GridCompute nodeCompute = grid.forNodeId(uuid).compute();

compute.call(callable);
```